# Solution of non-linear Fredholm (Hammerstein) equation with non-degenerate kernel and reciprocal non-linearity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, operator-theory, integral-kernel

I have asked this question [at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1151638/166535) but got no response. I have rephrased it so that anyone who knows operator theory and integral equations could help me out... I faced a problem in physics which is a non-linear Fredholm integral equation (Hammerstein). It is of the form:
\begin{equation}
y(p)=f(p)+\int_0 ^{\infty}\frac{e^{ik∧p}}{y(k)}dk
\end{equation}
There are two subtleties:

1. The kernel is non-degenerate or non-separable.
2. The non-linearity is reciprocal.

The kernel is symmetric as the wedge product is anti-symmetric,i.e. $\overline{K(p,k)}=K(k,p)$. I tried solving it using the collocation method but got divergence due to it's severe bound on the upper limit. I am now starting to work with Monte-Carlo integration and it's too complicated. That's why I want to know if any of you could help me.

Comment: Where did you ask this question previously? It would be nice to provide a link to avoid duplication of efforts.

Comment: i asked it in math.stackexchange...

Comment: I added a link to your question and made minor other edits. Feel free to re-edit if you want to.